# Subclassing WPF Window

Tags: wpf, subclassing

I created a WPF Window

than i modified its class definition to:

```
public partial class myWindow : mySubclassedWindow
```

compiler throws:

***"Partial declarations of 'myWindow' must not specify different base classes"***

myWindow.Xaml:

```
x:Class="WpfGridtest.myWindow"
```

so somewhere, there is another partial class, that inherits from "Window" but i cannot find it. How can i override my case to use subclassed window?

---

thanks Jon, that was the problem.
also found this helpful article:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815091447/http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/02/107747.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be in the declaration of `myWindow` itself - the designer will be generating the other half of the partial type based on the XAML, based on your element type.

You can use an element of `<mySubclassedWindow>` instead, so long as you give it the appropriate namespace and assembly references.

EDIT: Okay, so here's a short example, in a project called WpfApplication. My `Window` subclass:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public class EnhancedWindow : Window
    {
    }
}
```

My XAML:

```
<y:EnhancedWindow x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:y="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
</y:EnhancedWindow>
```

My partial type:

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : EnhancedWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

It all builds with no problem. I think that's what you wanted to do, right?

Comment: thanks Jon, do you mean the <Window part at the very beginning of file? how can i modify that to use the subclassed version?

Comment: @Sonic: Yes, that's what I mean. And you'd need to modify it to refer to your subclassed type instead of `Window`. I'm just trying to come up with a short demonstration...

Comment: @JonSkeet There is very interesting behave with this solution, using EnhancedWindow in XAML doesn't give intellisense, it does if EnhancedWindow  referred from external assembly.